# imageview source image size

Tags: android, imageview

I am reasonably new to android development and have a question about the ImageView widget.

I have a jpg image that I wish to use as a backdrop for my app on Nexus 5 so I sized it at 1080x1920. I add the image to my drawables and set the ImageView src and sset ScaleXY.

When I try and run the "Failed to allocate a 74649612 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM" error in the Nexus 5 emulator. If I try and run the app on a nexus 5 I get an error warning that the image is too big but and it mentions a resolution that is twice the size of the actual jpg.

However, if I try and run the app on the nexus 4 emulator it works.

So to sum my question up, I want to understand why an image that is the same size as the physical screen appears to be being scaled up internally by the ImageView object. And how can I get a full resolution image displayed on the device without this issue.

Baz

Comment: Did you add the drawable only once, or did you add it in all the screen densities?

Comment: I added it only once and only got one screen design

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your virtual device's ram.  The solution is to edit `C:\Users\.android\avd\.avd\config.ini` and change the value

hw.ramSize=1024

to

hw.ramSize=1024MB

Comment: The emulator is already set to 1.5GB and besides the app does not even run on a physical Nexus 5 phone